# User having onedrive issues

Tags: microsoft-office-365, onedrive-for-business

A client of mine i setup user permissions for their business ( files kept getting deleted or misplaced so i changed it that they cant edit since when you make changes it deletes the file and replaces it with the new one, thus putting me in a pickle here) 
so i was trying to setup special permissions for this one user to be allowed to make edits and changes since she is the one who does this the most.

I tried to show her the work around where you download and upload the document in its new version with a different title so its not trying to replace the previous file causing it to not upload.

well.

she did it, she did it with out the new name and it tried to replace the old file and now stuck in an asynchronous loop where the file keeps replicating over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Users mistakenly delete files. They mistakenly move files. It happens. This is why you (should) have backups. Making it so that users can't work with the files they need to do their jobs isn't a solution.

Unsync the folder in question. Then come up with a solution that actually works for the users and is sustainable.